# Stuck with mix quotation marks

Tags: php, javascript, html

i am writing a code but it is showing me error with due to quotation marks...please point it out. The error is in the "value" but i dont know how to solve it..

```
 <?php
  echo "<input id='u_name' type='text' name='u_fname' value=".if($row['fname']!=''){echo $row['fname'];}." />";
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[If](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.if.php) is not function. You cannot concatenate it.

```
<?php
  echo "<input id='u_name' type='text' name='u_fname' value='";
  if ($row['fname'] != '') echo $row['fname'];
  echo "' />";
?>
```

Or you can use [ternar operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).

```
<?php
  echo "<input id='u_name' type='text' name='u_fname' value='".($row['fname']!=''?$row['fname']:'') . "' />";
?>
```

Comment: it worked...thanks alot...
Please tell me why u used semi colon right after value like
value='";
what was the purpose behind that

Comment: @AwaisUmar, it's end of operator.

Comment: ok thanks...i will accept the answer in 10 minutes...this is what they said me :-p

Comment: @sectus If is not needed. see my answer.

Comment: @MiroMarkarian if was needed as you dont know my realy code...if was necessary there...

Comment: is there any way to hide this value without using <input type="hidden" />?

Comment: @AwaisUmar, put value to javascript or hidden div.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the outer " to '

and then the inner 'fname' change to "fname"

This should work, worked for me when I first tried it. Actually, the if cannot be concatenated like that either. Just get rid of the full stop

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php echo "<input id='u_name' type='text' name='u_fname' value=".$row['fname']." />";?>
```

And actually if the $row['fname'] is not equal to null then it will be itself if equal to null it will be null so no need to if. simply it will return null. Which is the same as if.